# How would u get someones UUID?

Tags: python, uuid, licensing, hwid

so I am trying to make a HWID licensing software but I don't know specifically on how to get the UUID, with python code.

I've used this so far

```
import requests
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
import hashlib
f = open("License.txt", "r")
ID03 = f.read()
ID = int(get_mac())
ID2 = str(ID * 30) + str('YESITSME12')
ID3 = ID2.encode("utf-8")
hash_object = hashlib.md5(ID3)
hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
f.close()
if ID03 == hex_dig:
    print('VALID LICENSE!')
else:
    print("INVALID LICENSE! YOUR UID IS " + str(get_mac()))
```

but in order for me to put it in my software I use, I need to get the users UUID or so called HWID

Comment: are you asking how to get the exact same number as `wmic csproduct get uuid` ? or are you just trying to get a 32 digit unique number that is consistant every time? or?

Answer (score 0):

its not clear what you mean ... you can use `uuid.UUID(hashlib.md5(uuid.getnode()))`

(that looks like the result from `wmic csproduct get uuid`(but is not the same)

you could also just do `uuid.UUID(int=uuid.getnode())` but it looks a little funny

if you need exactly the same output as `wmic csproduct get uuid` ... you will need to use `subprocess`, or `os.popen` to call `wmic csproduct get uuid`